# Access outer scope variable in readFile

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, readfile

I'm new to asynchronous programming. Lately I've found a case that I do not really understand. For this example:

```
var username = "abc";
fs.readFile(filePath, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, oldUsername) {
    console.log(username); // Print xyz
    if (username == oldUsername) 
        // do something, since username is now 'xyz', result failed!
});
username = "xyz";
```

I want to compare the **oldUsername** which I got in the file to the **username** (abc) but the console print "xyz" so the result failed.

How do I get the unmodified value of **username**?

Comment: Changing the username inside of the callback seems to be your lonely choice. Or create a tmp variable that holds your value

Comment: @Skahrz This got me stuck for half a hour, you've just pointed it out for me. I'd just change the username inside the callback. There doesn't seem to be a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember, all that code in that callback function, it is not actually run until AFTER everything else in that code runs.

You are just DEFINING the function there, not executing it. You pass it in as an argument to the other function (readFile) so it will call that whenever it's done with it's async i/o.

I guess it's kind of like putting a return address on an envelope, it doesn't matter until after the primary address on the envelope is processed.

So you end up assigning a different value at the end there, BEFORE the console.log ever gets executed.

More info is out there, for example:

> A very interesting property of the event loop model is that JavaScript, unlike a lot of other languages, never blocks. Handling I/O is typically performed via events and callbacks, so when the application is waiting for an IndexedDB query to return or an XHR request to return, it can still process other things like user input. [[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Never_blocking)]

Good luck! :)

Comment: Although I've figured out async, this is still very helpful.